# Drop a shadow to right and bottom of uiview

Tags: ios, calayer, shadow

I have to drop a shadow to the right and bottom of uiview.Im doing this in interface builder.But I see the shadow dropped to top of it.Tried differnt sizes.but couldn't get it.

```
layer.masksToBound=No
layer.shadowOpacity=0.15
layer.shadowRadius=2
layer.shadowOffSet={10,-10}   //Values being set in Interfacebuilder.
```

Still this drops shadow at top.What should I do to get at bottom of view.

Comment: for runtime @walle84 is corrent answer.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Try the following code, it might help you

```
    myView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
    myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    myView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
    myView.layer.maskToBounds = NO;
```

I tested this code and it's working and output is:

[image]

Comment: Can u tell me how to add shadow only in bttom of the view.

Comment: Instead of  `myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);` do `myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 5);`

Comment: inimageview i can't add this shadow. i have coded like as you write.

Comment: Hey, I tried setting my cgsizemake(0,n), but i keep getting a shadow on the right side of the view... any idea why that is?

Answer (score 6):

Hi I have used below code ,it will provide you with shadow you want.

```
 UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_viewShadow.bounds];
_viewShadow.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
_viewShadow.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_viewShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 5.0f);  /*Change value of X n Y as per your need of shadow to appear to like right bottom or left bottom or so on*/
_viewShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
_viewShadow.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

Also masksToBounds is imp as it disables the clipping of sublayers that extend further than the view's bounds. If you put it YES then you won't see shadow as it clips sublayer where else in NO it allow to extent layer.

Comment: Thanks for your note on 'masksToBounds', I was missing this one.

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift 3**, `CGSizeMake` no longer exists. It has been changed to `CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)`. So the `shadowOffset` can be set like this in **Swift 3**:

```
myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that these values give a nice result :

```
myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
myView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1) // shadow on the bottom right
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your shadow offset is incorrect. It should be { 10 , 10} like:

```
[layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake( 10 , 10 ) ];
```

Comment: Use code to create shadows. check this [link](http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths)

Comment: @GauravSingh i used this to draw shadow for tableview cell but after scrolling up it  goes to top.